# Direnv not allowing me to allow

Tags: direnv

I've installed direnv (v2.18.2) onto my Ubuntu 16.04 machine using:

`sudo snap install direnv`

as per the website, and added the line:

`eval "$(direnv hook bash)"`

to my `~/.bashrc` file as per the instructions. When I navigate into the directory with my `.envrc` file, the following message shown:

`` direnv: error .envrc is blocked. Run `direnv allow` to approve its content. ``

Sweet. So I run `direnv allow`, and I'm immediately hit with exactly the same error. I've also tried using `direnv allow .` but that doesn't seem to help. Also, completely restarting my laptop hasn't helped either.

All the advice I've seen is for direnv not finding the `.envrc` file, but here it *is* finding it, it's just not allowing me to allow it.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is not a propper solution, but I encountered this aftering installing from a snap on Linux Mint.

After I uninstalled the snap and installed it from aptitude I did not have any issues.

Comment: Thank you @trauty_is_me, I was trying everything and nothing worked but this.

Answer (score 1):

While the OP is on Ubuntu I ran into the same problem with the snap installed binary on CentOS 7.7.

I worked around the problem by installing a [go binary](https://golang.org/dl/) and then building direnv from source: `git clone https://github.com/direnv/direnv.git; cd direnv; make; make install` which got me direnv 2.21.2 in /usr/local/bin